# Why devices that have same physical size and resolution may have different density?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, screen-resolution, huawei-mobile-services

I am testing on Huawei MediaPad T5 and Samsung Galaxy Tab A.
They have the same  fiscal size (10.1 inch) and pixel number (1920*1200),

Question 1: Why they have different density (2.0 and 1.5)?  Density dipendes only on fiscal size and pixel number, right?

Question 2: I gave the same width to the sidebar (150dp) using dp, why they look different?

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fcom_categories"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

huawei:
[image: huawei]

samsung:
[image: samsung]

PS: I printed there display specifications

Huawei  （xhdpi）

```
2019-03-31 17:37:23.801 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: displayName  = 内置屏幕
2019-03-31 17:38:05.072 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: width        = 1920
2019-03-31 17:38:05.072 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: height       = 1133
2019-03-31 17:38:05.073 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: widthPixels  = 1920
2019-03-31 17:38:05.073 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: heightPixels = 1133

2019-03-31 18:13:03.031 16436-16436/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: density   = 2.0
2019-03-31 17:38:05.073 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: densityDpi   = 320

2019-03-31 17:38:05.073 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: xdpi         = 225.777
2019-03-31 17:38:05.073 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: ydpi         = 225.777
2019-03-31 17:38:05.074 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: screenHeight = 1133
2019-03-31 17:38:05.074 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: screenWidth  = 1920
2019-03-31 17:38:05.074 15550-15550/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: orientation  = 2
```

Sumsung （hdpi）

```
2019-03-31 17:40:57.310 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: displayName  = 内置屏幕
2019-03-31 17:40:57.311 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: width        = 1920
2019-03-31 17:40:57.311 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: height       = 1200
2019-03-31 17:40:57.312 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: widthPixels  = 1920
2019-03-31 17:40:57.312 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: heightPixels = 1200

2019-03-31 18:12:15.386 25654-25654/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: density   = 1.5
2019-03-31 17:40:57.312 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: densityDpi   = 240

2019-03-31 17:40:57.313 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: xdpi         = 225.777
2019-03-31 17:40:57.313 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: ydpi         = 225.77701
2019-03-31 17:40:57.314 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: screenHeight = 1200
2019-03-31 17:40:57.314 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: screenWidth  = 1920
2019-03-31 17:40:57.314 24205-24205/com.ristoo I/DisplaySpecifications: orientation  = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to the manufacturer which pixel density bucket to choose. For example on something like a tv or tablet which is designed to be used further away from your face they might pick a lower density so items looks larger.

So although an item which is 150dp will be ROUGHLY the same size on all devices, there will still be some variation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! @matt. But this makes developers hard to develop a view that adapt all devices. For example, we can not decide a right size for the sidebar in the screenshot, "150dp", looks better on samsung, "100dp", looks better on huawei. We have to define all size programmatically to adapt all  display density?

Comment: @Shi: "We have to define all size programmatically to adapt all display density?" -- usually, you choose one value that looks acceptable, then move on to something else. Bear in mind that the user can choose the effective screen density and font scale in Settings, so beyond the 20,000+ device models, there are dozens of user-specified display characteristics.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the response. " move on to something else. " means I have to make all the value in xml (layout_width="150dp") as variables.  and change it according to the device density, right?(a lot work) Is there a best practice about this? Thanks!

Comment: @Shi: "I have to make all the value in xml (layout_width="150dp") as variables. and change it according to the device density" -- no. You choose one value for a given screen size and live with it. The precise width of this sidebar should not be among the top 100 things for you to be worrying about with this app. If, years from now, you have all the security issues, performance problems, OS version compatibility concerns, etc. fixed, then worry about optimizing this sidebar width.

Comment: @CommonsWare Right! Thanks a lot for the response!